# android "main cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i m new to this platform, please help me to find what is the error...
     setContentView(R.layout.main); // this line shows the error.

Code:

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a layout file called main.xml?

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting the line `import android.R` then clean your project.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding more details on why the error is coming.

As there is an import of android.R so setContentView() is looking for a layout file 'android.R.layout.main' and there is no main.xml in the layout files that come along with SDK. So, using the correct R.java import will work.

Comment: You mean to say that he has the wrong R class imported (project instead of Android or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

clean Project then try To Run because i faced same problem before a month and remember layout/main.xml must be their and it must not contains any error.
 you can Also Do this

`import android.R;`
**or**
`import your.application.packagename.R;` Now Clear Project and Run it.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to simply change the

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

... to:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

... because Layout contains this `.xml` file.

I hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

First remove    `import android.R;`

After any change on xml fiels you must clean project.

***Build > Clean Project***

after that every things corrects.